# Чому у словниках немає слова категоризувати?

Tags: дієслова, існування-слова, словники

Як називається дія за значенням "розподіляти в категорії"?

Я думав, що існує слово "категоризувати".

Але чомусь [СУМ-20](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40937&page=1293) і [Словники України онлайн](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) не знають цього слова.

А [ґуґл](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvJcPIb3avxGrmyen1ZSHwc3HhsZQA:1633555248342&ei=MBNeYbKjFLCrrgTV1orQDw&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiy-7DC27bzAhWwlYsKHVWrAvoQ8tMDegQIARA8&biw=1472&bih=703&dpr=1.3) ніби свідчить про досить широкий вжиток. Чи є якась причина невідповідності вжитку словникам?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Коротко

Це краще питати прямо словникарям.

Тому це питання можна оцїнити як таке, котре не має обєктівної відповідї. Але можна розглянути три можливі причини.

## Довго

*Тут переважно здогадки.*

Основна **проблема** в тім, же згадані словники обмежені папером. «Словник України online» може здати ся суто електронним, але насправдї [оснований](//lcorp.ulif.org.ua/pdf/Pro_Systemu.pdf) на [«Українському орфографічному словнику» 9‑го видання і 2009 року від «Довіри»](//nas.gov.ua/UA/Book/Pages/default.aspx?BookID=0000004082). Обмеження папером означає, же мусиш викидати певні слова. Тому, для порівняння, умовний СУМ‑11 має [134 058](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) слів, а ВЕСУМ — [416 766](//github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/blob/master/out/stats/dict_stats.txt), тобто маємо коефіцієнт біля 3,11, що чутливо коли мова про великі числа. І, недивно, ВЕСУМ має слова [*категоризувати*](//r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8). Ще вада паперових видань — їх не можна просто взяти і виправити, задля цього треба окрема книга, зазвичай перевидання. Хоча, гадаю, «Словник України online» можуть цього дозволити, але їм особисто про це треба вказати.

**Друга** причина, словники зазвичай мають за основу попередників. Очевидно, СУМ‑11 не мав такого слова, хоча декотрі корпуси вказують, що поодинокі вжитки були. Є ще одна особливість, беру з свойого досвіду щодо перекладачів i згадую совітської лінґвістічної практіки, українських укладачів — споглядати і слїдувати за московським, тут мова, звісно, про словники. Я про всяк перевірив за відомими жерелами, і виявило ся, вони теж зазвичай не мають такого слова: [Академік](//academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), [Ґрамота](//gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x). Слово згадують лише:

- Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин‑т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: «Азбуковник». В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.
- Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. — Чудинов А. Н., 1910.

Гадаю, же мало хто глядїти йме в словник 1910 року. А щодо ортоґрафічного, то є новіший:

- Орфографический словарь русского языка. 2006.

Котрий не має того слова, тому сітуяція могла ся повторити.

**Третя** причина. Звичайна помилка через недогляд. Або навпаки передбачливо подумали, же питоме слово як [*впорядковувати*](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%AF%D0%94%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A3%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98) краще заходе.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. До перших двох причин: саме тому сподівався на СУМ-20, адже він має більше простору для дії. Тому вважаю, що це ваша третя причина, яка свідчить про певну непрофесійність або недофінансованість словникарів. Не вважаю "впорядковувати" прямим відповідником, у нього не закладено груп, впорядкувати можна, наприклад, просто гарніше склавши, а тут саме розділення. Але відповідь загалом дуже сподобалась.

Comment: @P.Vowk Бо ви не розумієте слово. Упорядкувати - це якраз те, що тре. Розкласти по рядкам. Ось ваш розподіл. ... або ж розділення.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko розкласти по рядках можна випадковим чином. Зробити випадкові категорії? — сумнівно.

Comment: @P.Vowk Звідки така інформація?

Answer (score 0):

Джерелом подібних слів є отримання інформації з англомовних або англомовних через російські джерела та, можливо, інших.

Переважно люди не витрачають час на дослідження в тлумачних словниках та шукання походження слів та пристосування до української мови або ж підбір відповідних, бо ситуації деяких галузей не дають на це часу. Не може кожна людина бути обізнана в усіх філологічних основах і подібному.

Через це в обіг у відомих галузях входять все більше слів іншомовного походження, які часто не є виправданими. Через свою популярність вони впливають на мову все більшої кількості людей.

Десь хтось казав, що словники старіють на момент друку. А так як інформація, слова з новими значеннями, поглинуті слова з вужчими значеннями і багато інших варіантів асиміляції слів у сучасному світі розповсюджуються зі швидкістю світла, то словники просто не можуть так швидко друкувати чи передруковувати.

Також важливу роль грає мода. Зараз мода на іноземне. (Хоча коли у нас не було моди на іноземне?) Наприклад, з поточного, зараз голову Верховної Ради називають спікером. Хоча насправді такої посади немає. Але усі послідовно використовують цю назву посади. Яка може бути інша причина щодо використання?

На мою думку, вже потрібно вкласти час і натхнення в інтернет словник з певними прискіпливими правилами (відповідними сучасним запитам) щоденного пошуку та входження слів.

На жаль я не знаю де знайти подібні дослідження для спростування чи ствердження вказаних вище слів. Це є лише моєю особистою думкою. І, мабуть, є сенс перенести це окремим питанням ...